# Exclusion Script for Domain in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I'm looking to do an exclusion script on 2 domains.

Here's the current script, but I'd like to add another domain.

`domain(Email) == "noemail.com"`

Would I do it like this?

`domain(Email) == "noemail.com" OR "test.com"`

Answer (score 4):

You would need to explicitly state the comparison again for proper syntax. So it would need to be:

`domain(Email) == "noemail.com" OR domain(Email) == "test.com"`